# What is the equivalent of compound words created by joining them with hyphen?

Tags: adjectives, word-formation

In English, when using two or more words as attributive I join them with hyphens.

> If you're desperate for dual-GPU performance, the 18.4-inch Alienware 18 has a dual-GeForce GTX 880M option

> That was a I-know-what-I-do remark.

How do I use a group of words as attributive, in Esperanto?
I know the translation of *solar system* is *sunsistemo*, but how do I make a phrase like *solar system* an attributive? How does it work with, for example, three words?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "attributive". Can you give an example for the attributive phrase of "solar system"?

Comment: Those are hyphens: - (hyphen), – (n-dash), — (m-dash). One does not join words with n-dashes, but with hyphens ;).

Comment: @JohannesMueller "(of an adjective or noun) preceding the word it qualifies or modifies and expressing an attribute, as _old_ in _the old dog_ (but not in _the dog is old_) and _expiration_ in _expiration date_ (but not in _date of expiration_)"

Comment: @Joffysloffy Yes, that's correct. I noticed that after I wrote the question.

Answer (score 8):

I think the system would basically be the same as in English except that you would need to add a *-a* at the end to make sure it is an adjective if the last word isn’t already adjectival. The hyphens would be optional unless it would make the meaning unclear because Esperanto naturally combines words like this anyway. Here are some example usages:

From *Monato*:

> Dum tiu ĉi unua etapo neniu prezidanta kandidato gajnis pli ol duonon de la voĉoj, kaj do en dua etapo devis batali la **76-jaraĝa** ŝtatprezidanto Valdas Adamkus […]

kaj:

> Tiamaniere, mi estis ekskomunikita tiel de la por- kiel de la **kontraŭ-Albault-a** skolo.

From *La Ondo de Esperanto*:

> Foje angla ĵurnalisto pro **mi-ne-scias-kia** ekstravaganca scivolemo intervjuis min pri mia naskiĝloko kaj pri aliaj distaj aferoj.

From *Ĉu vi kuiras ĉine?*:

> Mi mense vidas ŝin miksi siajn venenajn fungojn aŭ **mi-ne-scias-kiun** mortigan likvaĵon.

There is even an example using the word *sunsistemo* in *Monato*:

> Pleje fascinis min (la unua artikolo) la klopodoj malkovri **ekster-sunsistemajn** planedojn.

Comment: In _mi-ne-scias-kiun mortigan likvaĵon_ _mi-ne-scias-kiun_ is not marked as adjectival. Is there any exception to _except that you would need to add a -a at the end to make sure it is an adjective_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno My understanding of grammar is probably too limited to say this with any authority but my assumption was that correlatives ending in _-u_ could be considered adjectival because they are used to describe a noun. That is what I meant by "unless it isn't already adjectival".

Comment: Isn't _-u_ just used with correlatives? In that case, doesn't it mean _related to person/people_? That is the only _particular_ example, since the other ones _obey_ to the rule you described. (One of those examples even ends in _kia_: _mi-ne-scias-kia ekstravaganca_.)